# Error de consulta en php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo el siguiente codigo que me deberia imprimir la cantidad de productos registrados de una tabla

```
  <?php
    require_once "js/conexion.php";
    $sql = 'select count(idp) as total from producto';
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if(!$result){
        die($mysqli->error);
    }else {
      $out = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
      echo $out['total'];
    }
    $mysqli->close();
   ?>
```

al momento de cargar la pagina me manda el siguiente mensaje

> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Intente correrlo de esta otra forma

```
  <?php
  require_once "js/conexion.php";
  $sql = 'select count(idp) as total from producto';
  $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
  if(!$result){
    echo "Error ";
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
  }else {
    $out = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo $out['total'];
  }
  $mysqli->close();
   ?>
```

Pero me manda este error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_error()
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\punto-venta\Admin.php:237 Stack trace: #0 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\punto-venta\Admin.php on line 237

Comment: Estas trabajando con la extensión MySQLi y no con MySQL, lo cuál provoca el error ... quizá quiso utilizar [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: al cambiar a mysqli_error me aparece el siguiente mensaje

Comment: Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter

Comment: Sería interesante saber en qué línea te tira el error *`Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`*, el cual suele ocurrir cuando no has terminado con una consulta y quieres lanzar otra. El código que pones al principio de la pregunta parece correcto. ¿Cuál es la línea del error específicamente?

Comment: No lanza la linea donde viene el error, solo aparece ese mensaje, lo que llegue a leer en varios foros es que probablemente tenga que ver con la version de php

Comment: Si revisas el log de errores es muy probable que te indique el archivo y la línea del error. A mi me da la impresión de que ese error está relacionado con otra parte del código. No veo ninguna anomalía en el 1er código que presentas. ¿Tienes más código relacionado que hace otro tipo de consultas a la base de datos o que intenta manipular esos resultados?

Comment: gracias por sus respuestas, me quede con el primer codigo, para resolverlo utilice require en lugar de require_once, de esta forma pude mostrar el resultado en el programa

Answer (score 1):

Pienso que no es necesario poner condicion a tu consulta yo usaria el:
Foreach $out as $fila
 echo $fila['idp'];

Comment: require_once "js/conexion.php";
              $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'select count(idp) as total from producto');
              if(!$result){
                echo mysqli_error($mysqli);
                exit; 

Le quite la condicion y ahora me muestra el siguiente error
Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: Quisas sea tu conexion q esta mal

Answer (score 1):

(PHP) El primer código que estás utilizando,posiblemente esté fallando, porque estás utilizando **mysqli_fetch_array($result)** y en la línea siguiente lo estás llamando como un array asociativo **echo $out['total'];**. Intenta llamarlo por un índice numérico.

**ES DECIR, DEBERÍA QUEDAR ASÍ...**

```
    $out = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
     echo $out[0];
```

[Aquí te dejo la documentación de MYSQLI_FETCH_ARRAY](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)